# Spring Boot dependency not found by Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

This is my build.gradle file

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'de.quinscape'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-context'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap")
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-context:.
```

What did I do wrong? I added all dependencies with Spring Initializer . and I'm only getting this error in that specific project.

Comment: AFAIK, `org.springframework.boot:spring-context` does not exist while `org.springframework:spring-context` does

Comment: What do you need org.springframework.boot:spring-context' for?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-context'`, spring context will be available automatically (with the indirect dependencies)